# Calculating the entropy of a non-trivial black hole solution

Tags: thermodynamics, general-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon

I am considering the calculation of the black hole entropy, given the [MTZ solutions for the mass and temperature](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0406111) (https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0406111):

$$M=\frac{\sigma r_+}{4\pi G}\left(\frac{r_+}{\ell}-1\right)$$

$$T=\frac{1}{\pi \ell}\left(\frac{r_+}{\ell}-\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

where $\ell$ is the AdS length, $\sigma$ is the area of the base manifold, and $r_+$ is the location of the event horizon. From other references, I know that the result should yield:

$$S=\frac{\sigma \ell^2}{4G}\left(\frac{2r_+}{\ell}-1\right)$$

Now, I want to calculate the black hole entropy by using the relation (Eqn. 1)

$$S=\frac{\sigma }{4G}R^2(r_+)$$

[(given on page 5 of the MTZ paper)](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0406111). I can see that $R^2(r_+)$ in Eqn. 1 is given in the metric (and I can find the exact solution for S given this information), but what is the physical intuition behind this expression? In other words, why can we say that $\sigma R^2(r_+)$ is the area contained within the event horizon?